# How To Dual Boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu in 32GB SSD

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, hard-drive, ssd

In my System I have a 32GB SSD and a 500GB HDD. I want to dual Boot My Windows OS and Ubuntu OS in the Same SSD HardDisk..but i am Unable to do that...afterwards i tried to install Both the OS in my 500 GB HDD, but it then also is Not Dual Booting....
Then i have Tried to Boot my Ubuntu in 32 SSD & Windows 7 in HDD, So While Booting it Starts with Windows 7...
So My Question is First of all How To Dual Boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu in 32 GB SSD..
and if Not Possible then...
Why is it Not Booting From 500GB HDD..
Please Help Me.....
Thanxx in Advance..

Comment: First thing: Did you install Windows after Ubuntu? In that case, there will be no dual-booting configured, since Windows simply installs the Windows bootloader and overwrites all others. Then second thing: Does your computer have UEFI? If yes, then make sure to install both, Windows and Ubuntu using EFI or both using BIOS emulation. If one is installed using EFI, and the other uses BIOS emulation, dual boot will also not be set up.

Answer (score 0):

Like soulsource said, always install windows, THEN install ubuntu. Ubuntu recognizes Windows and configures the Boot Manager.

jBut when you have 2 seperate discs, just install Win7 on 512GB SSD, plug it out. Install ubuntu on 32GB. shut down, plug in, boot and select bootable device in BIOS to boot. If you choose 512GB SSD in BIOS, boot win7, if you choose 32GBSSD, boot ubuntu. Most Bios versions have hotkeys for this. Mine has F11.

With this method you avoid any problems, boot managers can create.